# Remove class after submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove .hidden from the div below:

```
<div id="clicktoshow" class="hidden"><form></form></div>
```

When I test the jquery below it works:

```
    $(document).ready("#submitbtn").click(function() {
      alert('button clicked');
   });
```

When I use the same code but replace alert with:

```
   $('#clicktoshow').removeClass('hidden');
```

when I click the submit button, the code below doesn't remove hidden:

```
  $(document).ready("#submitbtn").click(function() {
      $('#clicktoshow').removeClass('hidden');
  });
```

Form:

```
  <form method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" id="the-form">  <input tabindex="165" id="submitbtn" type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Submit"></form>
```

Submit button:

```
 <input tabindex="165" id="submitbtn" type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Submit">
```

Question: Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Maybe something to do onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" on the form?

Comment: Ted's answer is what you're looking for. As a safe practice, always put `function() {<actual function here>}` inside event listeners. If you're looking to show and hide on button click, change `removeClass('hidden')` to `toggleClass('hidden')`

Answer (score 7):

You've got your doc ready functions a bit hinky. Try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitbtn").click(function() {
       $('#clicktoshow').removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

This adds the click listener after the document is fully loaded (as it should be). Anything you want to happen after the document is ready should be inside that function, not chained on it. So for future reference, it works like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //your code goes in here.

});
```

Comment: I was hoping this would work but it doesn't work.   The hidden class is still there and the form doesn't display.

Comment: @jygm then the problem lies elsewhere, not in the code you've provided. [Take a look at this demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/411fuwtb/), it works as expected...

Comment: The code is quite simple the issue is you're only thinking off the button but rather the form and submit button as an input.

Comment: @jygm Then I suppose you'll need to include the complete code to get an effective answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to correct the `$(document).ready()` to not include the id of the button so that the event is bound as soon as the page is fully loaded, ensuring the element is present.

It appears to work fine as shown below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitbtn").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#clicktoshow').removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <button id="submitbtn">Click Me</button>
    <div id="clicktoshow" class="hidden">Hello</div>
</form>
```

---

I would also suggest using `.on('click', function() {})` instead of `.click` so the code will still function as expected even if the element is dynamically generated.

Comment: Tell me this so I understand your post.  Who would actually add a button outside of <form></form> tags?  Put your button inside the form tags and see how well your code works.   Let me know what you get.

Comment: I have edited the post above and wrapped up the button and div in the form. I had to add `e.preventDefault()` to stop the form submitting. I accidentally left the <button> outside of the <form> in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you should use better scoping for your document.ready function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your event handlers and other code in here
    $("#submitbtn").click(function() {
        $('#clicktoshow').removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

By doing that you will ensure your code is encapsulated properly in the 'ready' handler. Now, let me know if this works for you, otherwise you may have to provide more detail regarding the rest of your code.

------------------------ Edit ----------------------

I thought that I could expand this answer to your question by highlighting aspects of hiding and showing an elements on click using jQuery. You can better leverage the jQuery library itself if you're already using event handlers. These are: [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). But my favorite usage is definitely [fading](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/). Take a look at those as you'll enjoy relying on these rather than having to extend your arm out to CSS every time. Keep in mind that this technique is great for using on elements, but if you're leveraging this on hundreds of elements then you will begin to see a slight drop in performance. Luckily that is not the case here :)

Comment: That's the same answer as above and it doesn't work. .  My code pretty simple submit the form the button is a input so that may be the issue.   Not sure. The whole page reloads

Comment: I just modified my answer right now regarding using jQuery hide/show and other functionalities you can leverage. Since it's only one element you should see no impact in performance. Give that a try and let me know if you get any new results.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code as your's. Make sure what css-class you want to remove.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").removeClass("intro");
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.intro {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<div class="intro"><form><p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p></form></div>


<button>Remove the "intro" class from all p elements</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well given the following markup

```
<div id="clicktoshow" class="hidden"><form>I'm here</form></div>
<button>test</button>
```

with the following JavaScript

```
$(document).ready('button').click(function(e) {
    $('#clicktoshow').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

works. Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/64apg6t2/1/

However, the [`.ready` function](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) usually accepts a handler and in the edge version of jQuery the above code will produce an error. So indeed you should use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitbtn").click(function() {
       $('#clicktoshow').removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Comment: Well yes it would work great if my form had just <form> </form> tags.  Look I did what the directions say on stackoverflow. It says to remove what isn't relevant to the question.  I thought people take into affect that I would not be using just <form></form> tags.   Normal action would be part of the form tag and onsubmit to validate the form etc. I mean who would actually in the real world add a button outside of the form tags? That makes 0 sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the submit() form event instead of the click submit button event.

```
  $(document).ready("#yourformid").submit(function() {
      $('#clicktoshow').removeClass('hidden');
      return true;
  });
```

And according to me it will be better to use a display none css for your div and perform a show(), like this

```
  $(document).ready("#yourformid").submit(function() {
      $('#clicktoshow').show();
      return true;
  });
```